# SSRS 2005 Subreports occasionally empty

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I have a "Parent" report that intentionally displays nothing, but queries a dataset of job numbers to be billed.  This Parent report then loops through those jobs, and passes them one by one to two SubReports.  The first SubReport is a summary of what will be billed on the job passed in.  The second SubReport is a breakdown of all the detail for that Job's invoice, Employee, Hours, Rate, etc.

There will be roughly 400 jobs submitted by the Parent to the SubReports.  The Summary report prints beautifully for all of them.  The Detail SubReport does so in about 90 - 95% of the cases, but on some jobs it is blank, and I see the error message saying something to the effect that the SubReport cannot be displayed.

When researching this, the most common response is that there is a problem with the way the parameter is being passed in.  That doesn't seem to be the case here, especially given that about 380+ of the 400 jobs show the detail beautifully.  So, I ran the specific query for that SubReport to see if I actually got data for one of the offending jobs.  Yes, hundreds of rows of data, so the data is there, the single parameter is being passed.

What else could cause this error?

The report continues on past the error, so that's good, but I need these detail sheets to display as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.  I post my resolution here for anyone who may be experiencing something similar even though this seems to be a rather bizarre circumstance. The issue was related to the Hidden property applied to various elements of a table.

At our company, groups of Jobs are assigned to Programs.  The Program Manager for one of these programs wants to see revenue subtotals grouped by "subjobs" in his program.  No one else cares to see this.  My solution was to create fields in the report (in the offending table) that have a visibility property set to true ONLY when it is his program being reported.

The grouping for these reports is Program/Job/SubJob.  I was applying the hidden property to various fields in the table using an IIF statement.  If it is his program, show the data, otherwise, don't.  As it turned out, something in SSRS 2005 was in conflict resulting from these hidden fields, but only on certain jobs, and this conflict was causing an "object not found" exception to be thrown when those jobs came through.  I'm still not sure what the conflict was, and why it didn't *always* appear.  About 95% of the report printed normally.

The solution was to move all hidden values to one column of the table, and apply the hidden property ONLY to that column.  Thus the entire column is hidden as desired, and everything in it obeys the hidden property of the column itself.

Answer (score 3):

To debug this kind of issue I take the following approach.

1. Work out if it's a specific set of data. I.E is it a particular set of job numbers. You do this by limiting query in some way (parameter, hard code etc.)
2. If it's data related, narrow down until you can find the actual datum causing the issue
3. If it's not data related then I narrow down the render technologies one by one.

   - First I use separate browsers
   - Then I try different report servers
   - Finally different report viewers (SharePoint native, direct, visual studio etc).

Usually I find it's a minor data conversion issue that throws the following data stream rendering out.

Don't discount bugs in the reporting systems either - you're using a legacy technology in my opinion.

N.B. Just because the subreport renders on it's own, it doesn't mean that it will work in conjunction with a master report. The way the different parts interact is also important.

Comment: Preet,  thank you for the prompt reply. I've been using a methodical approach similar to what you suggest.  
- I've hard-coded the job number where the parameter is 105880.
- I've gone straight to SQL Mgmt Studio and run the query there.

As you noted, this points me to a rendering issue.  

The only browser available is IE.  We're using Deltek Vision 6.2SP2 and that application is IE only.  The rendering issue appears there, and it appears in the Preview in SSRS 2005 (again, what is supported by Vision). It also happens when the report is printed to hard copy. (cont.)

Comment: There are hundreds of pages to these reports, and the offending pages are scattered throughout, while all other pages render properly.  There has to be something within the data of these reports that causes SSRS to hiccup.  I'll keep digging, but thought someone here might have it right at their fingertips.  This place is oozing with experience and wisdom.

Comment: Thanks, but you need to narrow it further and then isolate the technologies, and the best way to do that is to strip away more and more of the data and more and more of render technologies. Also you could be altering the Sp to return only the subreport data that is faulty.